# Using sklearn's PCA to find un-mean-centered components

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, pca

I am using sklearn's PCA for use in a physical modeling problem. In this problem, the return values from `PCA.fit_transform()` and `PCA.components_` have physical meanings. However, it seems that sklearn's PCA automatically mean centers the input data, so that the return values of `PCA.fit_transform()` and `PCA.components_` are in mean-centered space. I realize that `PCA.inverse_transform` returns the original un-mean-centered input data, but it does this through `np.dot(X, PCA.components_) + PCA.mean_` where `X` is the return value of `PCA.fit_transform()`.

In other words, how can I alter `X` and `PCA.components_` into `X1` and `PCA.components_1` by using `PCA.mean_` such that `np.dot(X1,pca.components_1)` returns the same value as `PCA.inverse_transform(X)`?

There is probably a simple linear algebra solution to this but I can't seem to figure it out.